# How to ensure tripod/camera safety when using remote

Tags: tips-and-tricks, paris, photography

I'll be travelling solo to Paris for business in December. I often use a tripod to take some artsy shots whilst I am travelling, but always with myself stood next to it taking photos of others. This time I was thinking about the possibility of taking some shots with myself in front of the camera using a timer/remote. ([Example](http://sandinourhands.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Paris-Instagram-spots-eiffel-tower-3.jpg) of the types of photo I will be going for)

I was wondering if anyone has any tips to ensure the safety of the camera and equipment whilst doing such shots? I will be attempting to take as many as possible during sun rise to minimise the amount of tourists around, but have always been worried about theft etc. especially in Paris.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is fundamentally a [photography.se] question and the travel aspect is largely incidental. Only people who are somewhat experienced photographers are likely to offer practical solutions, whereas a seasoned traveller with no interest in photography is unlikely to have anything useful to contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to have a friend near the camera, maybe you will find an other photographer and organize the morning tour together.

It is not just thief, but tourist are looking for photos and will step over your tripod, etc. It helps also to create a short "block" between you and camera.

Else, you should find a quiet spot, where you have a long field of view, if people are approaching. Thief tend to be on busier parts (near car parking/bus stop/queue/usual photo stops).